# How to load CSS and Bootstrap files into server using node.js?

Tags: html, css, node.js

I have a html file called myfile.html that displays 'Hello World'. My css file called myfile.css is used to insert background image. My bootstrap files are used to insert a image in the form of a circle.

The HTML file is as follows:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
         <title>MY FILE</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public\css\bootstrap.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public\myfile.css">
     </head>
     <body>
         <h1>Hello World!!</h1>

         <img src="public\pinky.jpg"  class="img-circle">
     </body>
 </html>
```

My CSS file is as follows:

```
body {
    background-image: url('fishy.jpg');
}
```

My node.js file called new.js is as follows:

```
  const express = require('express')
  const app = express()
  app.use(express.static('public'))

  app.get('/',function (req,res) {
          console.log(__dirname)
          res.sendFile(__dirname+"/myfile.html")
  })

  app.listen(3000, function() {
          console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
  })
```

My main folder is called Bootsstrap and it has the following contents:

```
     Bootsstrap
          -myfile.html
          -public /*Folder*/

         /*inside public folder*/
          -myfile.css
          -css
          -js
          -fonts
          -fishy.jpg /*background image*/
          -pinky.jpg /*circular image*/
```

I open Command Prompt from Bootsstrap folder and run

```
           node new.js
```

I get the message as:

```
          'Example app listening on port 3000!'
```

When I open Chrome Browser and type localhost:3000, I get only 'Hello World'.The images are not getting displayed. I get an [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQYCJ.jpg) 404.

What can I do in order to run my HTML file in server using node.js by including all my css and bootstrap files?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve static files, such as `html` files, `css`, images, you need to make them available for the public. In your existing setup, only `myfile.html` is available for the public. Since you use css and other files from your server, you need to make them available also. The best way to achieve is to create a `public` folder and let express to make all the files available in the `public` folder.

Add to node.js

```
   app.use('/', express.static('public'));
```

and rename your `myfile.html` to `index.html`

and in your `index.html` file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myfile.css">
```

For example, your node.js should look like something

```
  const express = require('express');
  const app = express();
  app.use('/', express.static('public'));

  app.listen(3000, function () {
          console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
  });
```

For more info [Serving static files in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

**Edit**

Your folder structure should be. no need of `bootstap` folder

```
      public //public folder
          -index.html
          -myfile.css
          -css
          -js
          -fonts
          -fishy.jpg 
          -pinky.jpg
```

Comment: I didn't understand. Could you kindly explain the code?

Comment: Where is the statement to create the route?

Comment: `app.use('/', express.static('public');` this is the route

Comment: But I am not getting it. It says Cannot GET

Comment: Try `localhost:3000/css/bootstrap.css` directly in browser and see can you see the css files or not.

Comment: I am getting everything in text format. I cant see any images

Comment: Change `<img src="public\pinky.jpg"  class="img-circle">` to `<img src="pinky.jpg"  class="img-circle">`

Comment: @Aarathi.V.B Check the edit for the correct folder structure.

Comment: `public` folder should be in the root of your project. not inside the `Bootsstrap` folder

Comment: Still everything in text format even after displacing index.html to public folder

Comment: can you please check the file structure again. And I made a typo in the `app.use('/', express.static('public'));`. Please check again the answer

Answer (score 0):

You must not use the `public` path in your html. Also, in URLs use always forward slashes. Backslashes are just for Windows directories.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>MY FILE</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myfile.css">
</head> <body> <h1>Hello World!!</h1> 
<img src="pinky.jpg" class="img-circle"> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Everything except bootstrap files came.
I am not getting the circular image.
The error is: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 pinky.jpg (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public\css\bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public\myfile.css">
```

by

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myfile.css">
```

Comment: Bootstrap files are getting included. I am not getting the circular image. The error is: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 pinky.jpg (Not Found)

Comment: Whats is the exact path of the 404 for pinky.jpg ? In Developer Tools, on Network tab you can see the url of pinky.jpg

Comment: You should change  img tag too:
<img src="pinky.jpg"  class="img-circle">